# CORS ISSUE trying to send data to my server

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, axios, cors

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/campgrounds/6411f03e718f68104cac045a' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/campgrounds') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

**This is my code on the front-end side of my app**

```
const instance = axios.create(
    {
        baseURL: '',
        withCredentials: false,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS'
        }
    })

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        instance.post(
            `${BASE_URL}/campgrounds`,
            inputInfo,
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            })
    }
```

**And this is my code from the back-end side of my app**

```
router.post('/', validateCampground, catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    const newCampground = new Campground(req.body.campground)
    await newCampground.save()
    res.redirect(`${BASE_URL}/campgrounds/${newCampground._id}`)
}))
```

but im receiving this error when i tried tor redirect(because the campground get saved in the db) at the end of the endpoint logic :
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/campgrounds/6411f03e718f68104cac045a' (redirected from 'http://localhost:5000/campgrounds') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Also, at the top of my backend im using the cors(()) package like this :

```
const corsOptions ={
  origin:'*', 
  credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
  optionSuccessStatus:200
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

I didnt know what im doing wrong... im tired of trying figured out .. i research a lot, i asked to chatgpt xd and i cant fix this issue.

PD : after handling the form with a onSubmit logic (controlled component), i was using the un-controlled approach sending my form data across the action/method props and having no issue, but when i change the approach like i showed after.... that f***** error.

please help me

just in case this is the repo > https://github.com/JulianOviedo/YelpCamp

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers do not belong in requests. You can safely drop them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cors always messes me up as well, I feel like I only deal with it every once in a while, so never enough to remember how I fixed it last time.

in this case though, I believe it's coming from the redirect in the back end, I think it's better if you returned the id to the front-end and then navigated to the url in the front-end

I would just have the backend handle the saving and return the id like this

```
router.post('/', validateCampground, catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const newCampground = new Campground(req.body.campground);
    await newCampground.save();
    res.json({ newCampgroundId: newCampground._id });
}));
```

then I would try something like this to redirect your page

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    instance.post(
        `${BASE_URL}/campgrounds`,
        inputInfo,
        {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            window.location.href = `/campgrounds/${response.data.newCampgroundId}`;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error: ", error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

request url on your frontend and backend must match to each other.
On backend:
router.post('/campgrounds', validateCampground, catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
// doing something
}

this should work
Your router.post() should catch a same url you send from client, if is is, then your code in that router.post will be executed and then enables the CORS policy as you wish, otherwise, it won't run.
You might want to delete your header{} in your request on client, because you cannot enable CORS on client side, so in this situation, it should not be there.

Comment: the urls match... in the backend its like just '/' but is a shortcut of the approach of use express.router to destructure. 
Im sure the urls match because like i said before.. the newCampground is getting saved ! but the problem is when i try to redirect